# Wordpress get option:selected value

Tags: wordpress

Build a quick plugin that makes use of dropdown menus in some instances.

Is there a wordpress correct way in recalling `option:selected` values?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `option:selected` values through the use of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).

But if you google a bit, you'll find many tutorials on creating drop down menus.
http://www.vanseodesign.com/wordpress/how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-in-wordpress/

and another tut if u are using 3.0
http://www.blog.web6.org/wordpress-3-0-drop-down-menu/